# Casting mysql reader result to string throws an exception in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, exception, casting

My function

```
public Permission[] GetPermissionsForGroupID(string groupID)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT `permissions`.`permissionName`, `groups_permissions`.`permissionValue` 
        FROM `db`.`groups_permissions`, `db`.`permissions` 
        WHERE `permissions`.`permissionID` = `groups_permissions`.`permissionID` 
        AND `groups_permissions`.`groupID` = '" + groupID + "'";
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<Permission> permissions = new List<Permission>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            permissions.Add(new Permission((string)reader[0], (int)reader[1]));
        }
        reader.Close();
        return permissions.ToArray();
    }
```

throws an System.InvalidCastException at

```
permissions.Add(new Permission((string)reader[0], (int)reader[1]));
```

I narrowed it down to `(string)reader[0]` where a `varchar` should be casted into a `string`.

```
reader[0] = permissions.permissionName = varchar
```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

The value of reader[0] is a string "kick_user_power" and the value of `reader[1]` is an integer "75".

**EDIT 2:**

The constructor of Permission

```
public Permission(string permissionName, int permissionPower)
    {
        PermissionName = permissionName;
        PermissionPower = permissionPower;
    }
```

And, for better visualization, the values of `reader[0]` and `reader[1]`:
[image: Reader-Values]

Comment: What is the value of reader[0], and, for that matter, of reader[1]  ?

Comment: and the constructor for the Permission class - how does that look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dotnet [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) class includes functions for retrieving column data.

You probably want to use

```
   reader.GetString(0)
```

and

```
   reader.GetSqlInt32(1)
```

to retrieve your values.

In fact for best results you should use

```
  reader.IsDbNull(0)? "missing value" : reader.GetString(0)
```

Comment: Nice idea. I will definetly refactor my code to use this approach. It worked perfectly fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it's not the cast to string that is the issue, but the cast to int?
Try

```
permissions.Add(new Permission(reader[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt64(reader[1])));
```

Both `ToString()` and `Convert.ToInt64` are a bit less "sensitive".

Comment: Nope. It didn't work. I made sure it is reader[0] by separately assigning its values to variables. (I didn't show that in the question but mentioned it by saying that I narrowed it down to reader[0].)